# Time Series Forecasting in Python for Numerous Time Series

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, imputation, arima

I have a network of sensors that output hourly/daily reads.
Some of these sensors are faulty and send out reads sporadically (once a week, once a month).  The sensors are not connected to one another, but they can be classified.  I ran a clustering algorithm to classify them based on their dry parameters (each is located in a different location with slightly varying definitions and specs).

For each faulty sensor, I predict/check the cluster to which it belongs and now I want to predict its read based on the reads of the other - non-faulty - sensors in the cluster.

It seems that ARIMA is the best fit for the data, but is there a way to build an ARIMA model for many time series and applying it to the faulty sensor's data?  Is there a better algorithm suited for this problem?

All help is appreciated.